# How to do a vlookup on 2 sets of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to error check a spreadsheet and make sure that the values of col A and B occur in col C and D

ex.

```
 Col A   Col B
   123    10
   456    11
   789    12

Col C   Col D
789      12     ----- this would be ok.. because the vaules show up in COL A And B
456      10     ------ this is not ok... this set of values does not show up in A And B
```

how would i do this without using VBA?

Comment: You can use a helper column by combining both columns, or use an array formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to add a helper column to concatenate A & B. Then you are going to concatenace D & E and lookup against the helper column.
so your data below and formula =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D1&E1,$C$1:$C$3,1,FALSE)),"BAD","GOOD")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
COL A1 = 123, COL B1 = 10, COL C1 = 789, COL D1 = 12
COL A2 = 456, COL B2 = 11, COL C2= 456, COL D2 = 10
COL A3 = 789, COL B3 = 12,
```

use the below formula in Col E1

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$3,2)=D1,"TRUE","FALSE")
```